# Making changes to Main Activity UI from thread in Service

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, service, handler

I've been looking for quite some time for some good documentation or a good example of this. I need to make changes to my main activity UI from the worker thread in my service which is running in the background. As far as I understand I know that I am suppose to work with some sort of Handler but I am not sure exactly how to approach this.

Does anyone have any ideas or good examples that they could direct me to? The UI element I am changing is a TextView that is simply informing the user of the status of the thread.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you have to do is to create a `Handler` on the UI thread:

```
private Handler serviceHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        someFunctionInTheUIThread();
    }
};
```

And then pass this through to your service.  You could have a function in the Service like this:

```
public void registerHandler(Handler serviceHandler) {
    handler = serviceHandler;
}
```

and then pass the handler through like this:

```
theService = ((LocalBinder) service).getService();
theService.registerHandler(serviceHandler);
```

then to send a message back:

```
Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(IDENTIFIER, "Message or data");
handler.sendMessage(msg);
```

Comment: Would it matter if I send the message from the thread in the service or from the onStartCommand? I am planning from sending it from both.

Comment: The beauty of Handlers is that they work across threads - read up here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html.  "A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects associated with a thread's MessageQueue. Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue. When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they come out of the message queue."

Comment: So if I have a worker thread in my service, it's not running in the same thread as the service, is it? Does that mean I have to make two handler's to send messages from the service methods and then from the thread? Sorry if these are stupid questions but threading confuses me.

Comment: No.  Create the `Handler` on the first thread (prob your UI thread) and then pass the handler all the way through to the worker thread in your service.  It should just work :)

Comment: What is the LocalBinder for. Do I need to write some code in my service before i use:
    theService = ((LocalBinder) service).getService();
    theService.registerHandler(serviceHandler);

Comment: Have a look at the example on this page : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 2):

Look into Service Binding. Or you could use BroadcastReceiver in your main activity to receive broadcasts from Service.

Answer (score 1):

You have to send an intent from your service with sendBroadcast(intent) and set a BroadcastReceiver in your activity

Comment: I tried that but I'm having some problems with it. I'll try the handler and then see if I can make the broadcast receiver work... 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a handler in onCreate() method in your main activity. This will create a handler in the UI thread. Then using this handler from the worker thread, call whatever you need to to get the TextView updated.