# How to display Service text updates on Screen in Android?

Tags: android-service, android

I am creating an Android activity and starting a service from this activity using the following code. Now I want to display text "Hello user" from this service to screen, meaning service should trigger this display. I could use Toast.maketext.show but the display will disappear after couple of seconds.

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startAdapterIntent.setAction("START_ADAPTER");      
            startService(startAdapterIntent);
            System.out.println("Thread2: Adapter Service started.");                
        }
    }).start();
```

How do I do that?

I tried to use this link:
[Making changes to Main Activity UI from thread in Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285785/making-changes-to-main-activity-ui-from-thread-in-service)

and its (probably) parent link
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html
section "Remote Messenger Service Sample"

While using this second link, the onServiceConnected part of ServiceConnection doesn't seem to be working? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From within your service you should create a handler that can be triggered by a timer task, the handler should be the one directly responsible of doing the communication with the currently active UI thread..an example would be

```
    long delay  = 3000;
    long period = 3000; 
    TimerTask mDoTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            xHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(xHandler, SOME_OPERATION));
        }
    };
    mT.scheduleAtFixedRate(mDoTask, delay, period); 
Handler xHandler=new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message){
            switch (message.what){
            case SOME_OPERATION:
                YourMethod();// in this method you can display your text 
                break;
            }
        }
     };
```

Comment: hey akajaymo, xHandler definition should be in activity right? Now how does service know about this handler? also i tried this method as shown in the second link but failed because I am not able to bind properly and so am not able to send messages properly. Could you please elaborate properly or give the complete (minimal required) working code.

Comment: No...all this code runs on the Oncreate in your service....basically the pseudo code would be: create a task..that runs after a few minutes,seconds etc...when this task runs what it does is sends a message to the handler. The handler will then work accordingly and run  the method. in our case it will run the method YourMethod(), whic you have defined and added code to render a message